# using tabs in a ui-router app without states for each tab

Tags: angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-router

I'm currently developing an angular appp with ui-router and want to use tabs in one view. As typical tabs implementation involves using relative links (#tabId) it conflicts with ui-router state change.
Is there a way to implement tabs without having to create an state for each tab?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can use,mateial Js tabs with angular which works well for tabs, and no conflict with ui-router states,
[reference](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/tabs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have used the tab-collapse bootstrap plugin (https://github.com/flatlogic/bootstrap-tabcollapse).

I had to change a little the code to avoid using the href attribute but managed to use tabs plus an automatic mechanism to convert tabs to accordions on small devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to url is changed, try to use query string

```
state('app.sample', {
  url: '/sample?tab',
  params: {
    tab: {value: null, squash: true} // for make param optional
  }
}
```

or like this

```
state('app.sample', {
    url: '/sample/:tab',
    params: {
      tab: {value: null, squash: true}
    }
}
```

and in controller you can operate with $stateParams

```
$scope.currentTab = $stateParams.tab || 'defaultTab';
```